# How can I fix the error 'Received unexpected config entry "params" at path root:postgres_db' when running the Dagster default mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, dagster

I have deployed Dagster on AWS EKS following Dagster guide using Helm https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/guides/kubernetes/deploying-with-helm.

When I try to run the Default mode as per above guide I get the following error message in the job log:

```
dagster.core.errors.DagsterInvalidConfigError: Errors whilst loading configuration for <dagster.config.field_utils.Selector object at 0x7f48e3ede750>.
Error 1: Received unexpected config entry "params" at path root:postgres_db. Expected: "{ db_name: (String | { env: String }) hostname: (String | { env: String }) password: (String | { env: String }) port?: (Int | { env: String }) username: (String | { env: String }) }".
```

Any tips to overcome this error message would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might derive from a mismatch between the `user-code-example` image tag and the daemon/dagit image tags, as described [here](https://dagster.slack.com/archives/C014N0PK37E/p1623777218106300) and [here](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/4649).

When configuring the helm chart, set the user-code tag to whatever the daemon/dagit is.

```
  deployments:
    - name: "k8s-example-user-code-1"
      image:
        # When a tag is not supplied, it will default as the Helm chart version.
        repository: "docker.io/dagster/user-code-example"
        tag: ~. # <-- wrong by default
```

As of writing, that is `0.12.8`.

Comment: Yes I realized that after a while... It does work when I specify a tag for the version. Thanks for confirming!